# "ImportError: No module named eventlog" with eventlog installed

Tags: python, django, email, pinax

I am trying out pinax. It will not run:

```
cchilders:~/projects/pinax$ ./manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named eventlog
```

Then it says it's already installed

```
cchilders:~/projects/pinax$ pip install pinax-eventlog
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pinax-eventlog in /home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jsonfield>=1.0.3 in /home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pinax-eventlog)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django>=1.4.3 in /home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from jsonfield>=1.0.3->pinax-eventlog)
You are using pip version 8.0.0, however version 8.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "bootstrapform",
    "pinax_theme_bootstrap",

    # external
    "account",
    "metron",
    "pinax.eventlog",
    # "eventlog",

    # project
    "pinax",
]
```

???

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named eventlog
```

requirements

```
Django==1.9.2
pinax-theme-bootstrap==7.2.0
django-user-accounts==1.3.1
metron==1.3.7
pinax-eventlog==1.1.1
```

Even though it says it's installed, doesn't seem to be there:

```
cchilders:~/.virtualenvs/pinax/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls
account                              django_user_accounts-1.3.1.dist-info  metron-1.3.7.dist-info                 pkg_resources              six.pyc
appconf                              easy_install.py                       pinax                                  pytz                       wheel
bootstrapform                        easy_install.pyc                      pinax_eventlog-1.1.1.dist-info         pytz-2015.7.dist-info      wheel-0.26.0.dist-info
django                               jsonfield                             pinax_theme_bootstrap                  setuptools
Django-1.9.2.dist-info               jsonfield-1.0.3.dist-info             pinax_theme_bootstrap-7.2.0.dist-info  setuptools-19.4.dist-info
django_appconf-1.0.1.dist-info       _markerlib                            pip                                    six-1.10.0.dist-info
django_bootstrap_form-3.2.dist-info  metron                                pip-8.0.0.dist-info                    six.py
```

Why doesn't the default pinax app work? Thank you

Comment: What is the actual module name in `/home/cchilders/.virtualenvs/pinax/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?  Is it `eventlog`, `pinax-eventlog`, or something else?

Comment: it isn't there. doing a pip install says it's there

Comment: it is underneath the pinax app, in `pinax/eventlog`